# Output of Iterable.sliding as Tuple

Tags: scala, collections

The method **sliding** on collections returns a sliding window of given size in the form of `X[Iterable[A]]` with X being the type of the collection and A the element type. Often I need two or three elements and I prefer to have them named. One ugly workaround for `sliding(2)` is the following:

```
points.sliding(2).foreach{ twoPoints =>
      val (p1,p2) = (twoPoints.head,twoPoints.last)
      //do something
}
```

This sucks and only works for two elements. Also note that

```
(a,b) = (twoPoints(0),twoPoints(1))
```

doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of what the question is.

Comment: I whined about the very same thing last week. The (A?) problem is certainly that due to some silly/unlucky/unexplainable design, you can apparently only have tuples up to size twenty-something. So `sliding` would not be well defined for larger inputs than that.

Comment: @Raphael: Also, the Tuples doeen't have a parent class more specific than Product. Also, the impl of such a class would inevitably be a vast switch statement keyed off of the number of elements. Who'd want to code that.

Comment: Something like `Array[(Any, ClassManifest)]` paired with some cast magic should do the job, too. This particular application would even require only a "nice" implementation of homogenuous tuples. Also, I do not quite get why not `apply(#)` is the accessor of Tuple but this awkward `_#`. In any case, having `Tuple` as hardcoded as it is definitely reeks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I did a lot of that in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656706/how-to-find-same-value-rectangular-areas-of-a-given-size-in-a-matrix-most-efficie/4697998#4697998) answer just last week.

```
points.sliding(2).foreach { case X(p1, p2) => ... }
```

If `points` is an `Array`, then replace `X` with `Array`. If it is a `List`, replace `X` with `List`, and so on.

Note that you are doing a pattern match, so you need to `{}` instead of `()` for the parameter.

Comment: I don't expect it will get any better, so I've accepted this.

Answer (score 4):

`twoPoints` would appear to be a List. Try this:

```
points.sliding(3).foreach{ _ match {
  case Seq(a, b, c) => {
      //do something
  }
}
```

You'll be surprised what sorts of kung fo pattern matching lets you get away with.

Comment: Ok, it works in the repl but gave me an error in the project.

Comment: @ziggystar: Oh boy. Works for me on scala 2.8.0. Which version are you on? Might also try case Seq(p1, p2) =>

Comment: @Ziggystar: Smells like a version problem. You might have multiple version dependencies, for which the maven plugin as a check.

Comment: @ziggystar - Are you sure `points` is a list in the project?  If it's some other kind of collection (e.g. an array) then the sliding entries won't be lists, they'll be the most natural thing for that collection to turn into (e.g. another array).

Comment: @Rex Kerr: Good point. I changed it to a Seq, which works just as well in REPL

Comment: The error in the project somehow complaint that List doesn't have an unapply. Then I tried it inside the REPL and it worked. No idea why that happened. I'll try again this evening and post the error.

Comment: The `match` is completely unnecessary. You can go from `foreach` to `case` directly.

Comment: Also, even `Seq` won't save you. It won't work for `String` or `Array`, for instance, both of which can be slided.

Comment: Ok, today again. Inside IDEA, from `val normals = points.sliding(3).map(_.toList).map{ case List(in,p,out) =>      val (vl,vr) = (in - p,out - p); (vl+vr).normalised}` I get "error: object List is not a case class constructor, nor does it have an unapply/unapplySeq method
val normals = points.sliding(3).map(_.toList).map{ case List(in,p,out) =>"

Answer (score 2):

I recently wanted a little more sugar in my sliding iterators, so I came up with this:

```scala
implicit class SlidingOps[A](s: Seq[A]) {
  def slidingPairs = (s, s.tail).zipped
  def slidingTriples = (s, s.tail, s.tail.tail).zipped
}
```

This works with any `Seq`, but is probably most efficient with `List`. `.zipped` returns a [`scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/runtime/Tuple2Zipped.html) (or [`Tuple3Zipped`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/runtime/Tuple3Zipped.html) for a 3-element tuple) object, which defines several familiar higher-order methods so that their arguments take multiple arguments, so you can write:

```scala
points.slidingPairs.foreach { (a, b) => ... }
```

or even:

```scala
(1 to 10).slidingTriples.map(_ + _ + _)
```

You can optimize the implementation further if you want it to be really efficient for non-list types.