# Scala list comprehension taking two elements at a time

Tags: list, scala, list-comprehension

Assuming that I can be assured I have a list with an even number of elements, such as

```
val items = List(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

I know that I can write a list comprehension taking one element at a time:

```
for (item <- items) println(item)
```

However, is there any way I can use a comprehension to process 2 or more elements at a time?

```
for ((first, second) <- items) println (first + second)
```

Comment: potential duplicate see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717742/output-of-iterable-sliding-as-tuple

Comment: Do you want to process first and second, then second and third? or first and second, then third and fourth? for the former, you want `sliding`. For the latter, `grouped`

Comment: @Gavin, since the OP tells us the list has an even number of elements, I suspect he wants `grouped`, not `sliding` so that's not a duplicate

Comment: It is always the case the the number of list elements is a multiple of 2, so in this case it indeed seems like grouped is what I am looking for. Eastsuns answer below solves my problem perfectly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here it is:

```
scala> val items = 1 to 6 toList
items: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

scala> for(List(first, second) <- items.grouped(2)) println(s"first: $first, second: $second")
first: 1, second: 2
first: 3, second: 4
first: 5, second: 6
```

Comment: But this is inefficient. You're building n/2 lists just to decompose them. (And building means ListBuffer, not a :: b :: Nil.) Using zip is better.

Answer (score 14):

Also consider using `zip`, like this,

```
for ( (f,s) <- items zip items.drop(1) ) println (s"f: $f, s: $s")
f: 1, s: 2
f: 2, s: 3
f: 3, s: 4
f: 4, s: 5
f: 5, s: 6
```

Or for every third element,

```
for ( (f,t) <- items zip items.drop(3) ) println (s"f: $f, t: $t")
f: 1, t: 4
f: 2, t: 5
f: 3, t: 6
```

Comment: Even better is `(items, items drop 1).zipped` so you don't create the intermediate list of tuples. If they weren't lists (with efficient drop), also `items.iterator zip (items.iterator drop 1)`.

Comment: @chrsva He wanted the behavior of 'grouped' which result in pairs with different ellements (1,2)(3,4) and not (1,2)(2,3).  To prevent all the lists creation one can use: `for ((first,second) <- (items.partition(_ % 2 != 0)).zipped) println (s"first: $first, second: $second")` (and of course it worth only if the list is big)