# How to merge Arrays in Array of Arrays?

Tags: arrays, scala

I have an `Array[Array[Int]]` and what i want to do is, per two of the inside `Arrays`, merge their elements to one `Array`.

E.g. I have: `Array(Array(1), Array(2), Array(3), Array(4))`

What i want as a result is:

```
 Array(Array(1, 2) Array(3, 4))
```

Is something like this possible in scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
myArrays.grouped(2)      //Iterator[Array[Array[Int]]]
        .map(_.flatten)  //Iterator[Array[Int]]
        .toArray         //Array[Array[Int]]
```

Comment: Oh, i didn't know `grouped`. That works like magic, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
val arrArr: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(
  Array(1),
  Array(2),
  Array(3),
  Array(4)
)
arrArr.grouped(2).map { l => l.flatten.toArray}.toArray
```

Comment: Reference link: [`Scala` list comprehension taking two elements at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25760276/3679900)